# How to copy a file to a new file with a new name in same directory but across multiple directories in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to copy an existing file (that is found in across directories) to a new file with a new name in Bash.  For example, 'Preview.json' to 'Performance.json'.  I have tried using

```
find * -type f -name 'Preview.json' -exec cp {} {}"QA" \;
```

But ended up with 'Preview.jsonQA'.  (I am new to Bash.)  I have tried moving the "QA" in front of the {} but I got errors because of an invalid path.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve.  Can you give a concrete example, including paths, of a source and its corresponding desired destination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an `-exec` predicate, the symbol `{}` represents a path that is being considered, starting at one of the starting-point directories designated in the command.  Example: `start/dir2/Preview.json`.  You can form other file names by either prepending or appending characters, but whether that makes sense depends on the details.  In your case, appending produces commands such as

```
cp start/dir2/Preview.json start/dir2/Preview.jsonQA
```

which is a plausible command in the event that `start/dir2/Preview.json` exists. But `cp` does not automatically create directories in the destination path, so the result of prepending characters ...

```
cp start/dir2/Preview.json QAstart/dir2/Preview.json
```

... is not as likely to be accepted -- it depends on directory `QAstart/dir2` existing.

I think what you're actually looking for may be `cp` commands of the form ...

```
cp start/dir2/Preview.json start/dir2/QAPreview.json
```

... but `find` cannot do this by itself.

For more flexibility in handling the file names discovered by `find`, pipe its output into another command.  If you want to pass them as command-line arguments to another command, then you can interpose the [`xargs`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) command to achieve that.  The command on the receiving end of the pipe can be a shell function or a compound command if you wish.

For example,

```
# Using ./* instead of * ensures that file names beginning with - will not
# be misinterpreted as options:
find ./* -type f -name 'Preview.json' |
  while IFS= read -r name; do  # Read one line and store it in variable $name
    # the destination name needs to be computed differently if the name
    # contains a / character (the usual case) than if it doesn't:
    case "${name}" in
      */*) cp "${name}" "${name%/*}/QA${name##*/}" ;;
      *)   cp "${name}" "QA${name}" ;;
    esac
  done
```

Note that that assumes that none of your directory names contain newline characters (the `read` command would split up newline-containing filenames).  That's a reasonably safe assumption, but not *absolutely* safe.

Of course, you would generally want to have that in a script, not to try to type it on the fly on the command line.

Comment: Hey, thank you very much.  It worked great.  If I wanted to just the new file to have a new name completely (no prepending) like 'QAPerf2.json', what would I change in the cp.

Comment: @PKonstant, if you want to copy to a fixed base name, then replace `QA${name##*/}` with the desired name and replace `"QA${name}"` with the desired name.

Comment: How does one learn about what the '##*/}' and others?

Comment: @PKonstant, that's what the Bash manual is for.  You can probably access a local copy via the command "man bash".  You can definitely find a copy (but not necessarily for the exact version you are using) by performing a web search for "bash manual".